# phpmailer str_replace multiple times

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have the following setup:

```
        $message =  file_get_contents('./site/resources/external/template.html');
    $message = str_replace('[name]', $email['name'], $message);
    $message = str_replace('[password]', $password, $message);

    require './site/resources/external/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Username = "mymail";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->FromName = "Marc";
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject = "Din nye adgangskode";
    $mail->msgHTML($message, dirname(__FILE__));
    $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->From = $mail->Username;
    $mail->Send();
```

However when i try to send it, it does not send.

However when i do like this:

However when i do the following:

```
$mail->msgHTML(str_replace('[password]', $password, file_get_contents('./site/resources/external/template.html')), dirname(__FILE__));
```

it sends without a problem.

So how can i add multiple variables to my template ?

Comment: "It does not send" isn't a useful description. Exactly what is failing? What errors are you seeing? You could try using a template engine such as Smarty or Twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't see how the variable substitution of `$message` could be breaking your code, there is a multiple replacement form of `str_replace` that uses array arguments:

```
$mail->msgHTML( 
  str_replace( 
    array('[password]','[name]'), 
    array( $password, $email['name'] ),
    file_get_contents('./site/resources/external/template.html')
  ),
  dirname(__FILE__)
);
```

I suspect something else is wrong with your code, but this might be useful.